# Why removing line information from a preprocessed C++ source code makes it fail to compiler?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c-preprocessor

## Example

```
clang++-8 -std=c++11 somefile.cpp -E > q.e
clang++-8 -std=c++11 -x c++ q.e -c -o q.o
```

Works as expected.

Let's remove line information, like this:

```
# 1 "somefile.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 380 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 "somefile.cpp" 2
# 1 "../someheader.h" 1
# 1 "/usr/include/clang/8.0.1/include/stdint.h" 1 3
# 61 "/usr/include/clang/8.0.1/include/stdint.h" 3
# 1 "/usr/include/stdint.h" 1 3 4
```

---

```
cat q.e | grep -v  '^# ' > qq.e

clang++-8 -std=c++11 -x c++ qq.e -c -o q.o
```

---

```
qq.e:238:20: warning: '__format__' attribute argument not supported: gnu_printf [-Wignored-attributes]
    __attribute__((__format__(__gnu_printf__, 1, 2)));
                   ^
qq.e:311:12: warning: keyword '__is_void' will be made available as an identifier for the remainder of the translation unit [-Wkeyword-compat]
    struct __is_void

(many more warnings)

qq.e:36194:3: error: constexpr function never produces a constant expression [-Winvalid-constexpr]
  acos(float __x)

...

fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
```

## Question

Why removing information that is supposedly should only affect messages from compiler actually affects compilation outcome?

Comment: Here's a bit of info that will help you understand why. Many system header files will not survive getting compiled when all warnings are turned on, and are fatal (gcc's `-Wall -Werror`). As such, the preprocessor marks code that comes from a header file, so the compiler can turn this off. Something quite analogous happens here, too.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, `#pragma`s are allowed by the regular expression. There are various `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored` in `qq.e`.

Comment: The particular functionality that I'm referring to does not employ pragmas. Pro tip: do file+line directives, shown above, appear to have something extra on them? Have you ever wondered what does that extra "3" is doing there, on the line that informs you that compilation switched to line #1 of stdint.h? This is actually documented in pubilc gcc documentation, I found it the other day.

Comment: Please create [MCVE] - please post the content of somefile.cpp.. I can't reproduce - `printf "%s\n" "#include <iostream>" "int main() { std::cout << 'a'; }" | clang++ -std=c++11 -E -xc++ - | grep -v '^# ' | clang++ -std=c++11 -x c++ -` generates warnings (related to system headers), but compiles fine. Technically, would be better to use `-xc++-cpp-output` for second stage. I have clang 12.0.1 on linux.

Comment: @KamilCuk Tried similar simple example with `g++` and it also works fine (even without the warnings). Original file was large and private (and I forgot where is it from), so it's tricky to reproduce and minify it.

Comment: If it's big, still go with creating MCVE - remove lines, until you have the smallest set of lines that causes the error. Surely 99% of the file can be removed. Note that warnings will pop up - some warnings are inhibited from system headers. Please post the first or some of the first errors that come up. Are you on windows/linux? `

Comment: @KamilCuk It was on Linux, building legacy-ish cross-platform C++11 code (big part of which is C++98). Is there a tool to automate creating C++ MCVEs?